# Index creeping in when converting GeoJson to gpd

Tags: geojson, geopandas

I am using a list of keys (`list_of_keys`) to extract .yaml dictionary (`dict`) values and read in some `.geojsons` whose names correspond to the dictionary values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
values = []
geometry = []

for i in list_of_keys:
    vals = dict.get(i)
    path_to_file = path + '/' + str(vals) + '.geojson'
    file = gpd.read_file(path_to_file)[['geometry]]
    values.append(vals)
    geojson_geometry(file)
df['values'] = values
df['geometry'] = geojson_geometry
```

I would like an output df like this

```
values     geometry
Britain    MULTIPOLYGON (((1.8...
```

however, when I am joining the two lists, it changes to

```
Index    values    geometry
0        Britain   0    MULTIPOLYGON (((1.8...
```

note the `0` before `MULTIPOLYGON` in the `geometry` column. The `file` df looks like this (1, 1)

```
Index      geometry
0          MULTIPOLGON (((1.8...
```

so the `0` creeping in during the joining of the lists. I suspect it's taking the Index value and joining the strings(?). This `0` is preventing further analysis such as `.buffer`, giving me the error
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'buffer'`

The analysis I am trying to perform has worked on other dataframes of geometries without the `0`, so I know that works. Does anybody know how to remove these or of a work around?

Comment: One thing that I just noticed is that df is a df (of course), but the dataframes that I have previously performed analyses on are GeoDataFrames.

Comment: What `geojson_geometry()` does? I assume that will be the issue. `file` is GeoDataFrame, the rest DataFrame, which is something you might want to resolve as well.